# Turn on location prompt fails when android device is in flight mode

Tags: java, android, location

Context
I have this application which requires a user to turn on location before doing any activity since we log the location as they move,however,some of my users choose to stay in flight mode while moving.All my users use android version 4.4 Samsung Galaxy J1 that is not rooted.
Our users are based in remote areas with  no wifi signals and weak network signals so we only use gps to get location.
The image below shows the prompt when flight mode is off and location is off in the app.

[image: Expected prompt]

Problem:

Unfortunately,when in flight mode,the user is not prompted to have his location turned on.The code used is as shown below from [google](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi)

```
public void getLocationSettings()
{
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient,
                    builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            //final LocationSettingsStates = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can
                    // initialize location requests here.

                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                    // by showing the user a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way
                    // to fix the settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When in flight mode and location is off ,this check will always result to SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE 
Hence we will not be able to do any activity.
However,this other code check below for location only will be able to get location settings even when user is in flight mode.

```
    public static Boolean gpsStatus(Context context)
{
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context .getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}
```

However ,with the  approach above,I am not able to execute this code below which prompts user to turn on location by clicking okay on the dialog:

```
    // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
// by showing the user a dialog.
try {
  // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
  // and check the result in onActivityResult().
  status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
} catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
  // Ignore the error.
}
```

The code above prompts a user to click okay to have location turned on thus the user does not have to leave the app and go to settings to turn on location.
While checking out other applications that require location,I also noted that since it is the same location check used by google maps,when in flight mode and location is off.Google maps will also fail to remind user to turn location and only tell them to check their internet connection.Any ideas on best way to always check for location settings will be highly appreciated,thanks

Comment: Why not check if the user has airplane mode on and make an alert to notify him to turn it off? After that, check if the Location is turned on.

Comment: @Adrian-AlexandruComan,flight mode helps save on battery as our user activities happen in offline mode for the whole day.They only turn on mobile data in the evening.

Answer (score 0):

As of now,I am using both  checks to take care of both scenarios i.e prompt user to turn on location in the case flight mode is off and we can access the settings or just ask the user to go to settings and turn on location.
The code used is as shown below.With this approach we are able to always check for location settings successfully and take necessary action.

```
        //go through here if gps is off and in flight mode
    if (!NativeLib.gpsStatus(MainActivity.this) && NativeLib.isAirplaneModeOn(MainActivity.this))
    {
        NativeLib.showSettingsAlert(MainActivity.this);
    }
    else
    {
      getLocationSettings();
    }
```